Big, scary [comma?] project
Putting a modesty test toward your goals can be really helpful in:

- Ensuring you don’t burn yourself out
- Elevating anxiety around a big, scary, project
- Removing productivity shame throughout your goal-accomplishment journey

We assume that any big project is scary, and we want to make it more clear to the reader. Should we put comma after scary?
(My intuition says me the answer is yes, but it seems many natives omit it, at least on the internet.)

No - a comma should not appear after the final adjective in a list and before the noun. The comma separates the adjectives themselves, but once you're done listing them, you go straight to the noun without a comma.
The only reason that the adjectives are comma-separated is because they are coordinate adjectives (adjectives that separately and equally modify the noun rather than non-coordinate adjectives which work together).
